# Instagram feeds not available : Need some alternate to get the instragram user public content

Tags: php, instagram, feed, instagram-api

We used to get the user instagram feeds using the following API :

```
$query = array(
             'client_id' => INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,
             'q' => 'ladygaga'
         );

         $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?".http_build_query($query);

         $user_data = getcurldata($url);
.

$main_user_id = $user_data['data'][0]['id'];

                   $content_query = array(
                       'client_id' => INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID
                   );

                   $url_for_content = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$main_user_id/media/recent?".http_build_query($content_query);

                   $insta_data = getcurldata($url_for_content);
```

Now we are not getting the user feed from API. Instagram have changed their API setting based on APP.
They have started user authentication before the feed is provided to user. Also they say only 10 users can be added to a particular APP in sandbox mode and a APP can only get feed of this 10 users and at max last 20 post of them.

But we want feed of several users (artist all over the world) : eg: ladygaga, akon, etc. To get their data we cannot authenticate them on our APP. Also only 10 users authentication wont help as we need around 5k-10k Artist feeds.

Is there any alternative from where we can get this Feeds ? Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape instagram frontend data. Basically there is a user JSON feed at

```
'https://www.instagram.com/' . $username . '/?__a=1'
```

and media feed at

```
'https://www.instagram.com/' . $username . '/media/'
```

which can be paged with GET parameters `max_id`, `offset_id` and `count`.

Be warned though, that this frontend scraping may be against some Instagram policies and when accessed too harshly you can be blocked by Instagram.

There is a Node library [instagram-screen-scrape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-screen-scrape) that does this, you can view its source for hints.

Comment: This also has a good chance of breaking randomly, as Instagram can update that URL at any time. Their app'll work fine. Yours won't. Scraping 5-10k as OP intends to do will likely also get one's server blocked.

Comment: This is great info, did not know `max_id` was possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. As it stands now, you'll have to use an access token. Only having a client ID is no longer enough to access data from the API.
2. Within sandbox mode you will not be able to access data from any user aside from the ten users you invite to the sandbox. If you would like to access more than the sandbox users, you'll need to [submit your site](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/) to "Go Live". This requires a rigorous examination of your site by Instagram.

> But we want feed of several users (artist all over the world) : eg:
>   ladygaga, akon, etc.

Because of the new API rules, you will not be able to do this unless you invite ladygaga, akon, etc. to your sandbox. I did something similar where I wanted to view my follower list. I kept getting empty JSON objects back where `data: []` had no input. I had to create a fake account and follow my real account. After doing this, requesting my follower list resulted in getting ONE user, the fake user that I made and invited to my sandbox.

---

IMO Instagram has completely nerfed their API and made it inaccessible to all but production-ready services. Handling pagination is especially more difficult now as you won't be able to test against it since the sandbox mode adds a limit to your follower list or media that you can request at one time.

I'm sure Instagram has valid reasons for this recent change, but I'm not happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can visit  below link,
https://www.dialogfeed.com/best-tips-for-instagram-api-update/

It is not free, you may contact them for pricing.

```
**Is there an alternative to Instagram API ?**

Yes, you can use third party providers, like Dialogfeed as we have been approved by Instagram.
We provide you with a platform to create your widget or an API delivering Instagram feeds. Your choice.
```

It seems it is the alternate to get the Instagram User public content.

Answer (score 0):

Me and community have written this library that do exactly what you want to:

https://github.com/raiym/instagram-php-scraper